# Open generic combined with another interface

Tags: c#, autofac

I'm using autofac as a container and want to register a open generic along with another interface, but cant get it working.

```cs
public class OpenWindowHandler<TViewModel> : IHandle<OpenWindow<TViewModel>>, IStartable, IDisposable where TViewModel : Screen
```

I register it using:

```cs
var genericOpenWindowType = typeof(IHandle<>).MakeGenericType(typeof(OpenWindow<>));
builder.RegisterGeneric(typeof(OpenWindowHandler<>))
    .As(genericOpenWindowType)
    .As<IStartable>()
    .SingleInstance();
```

The error I get is

> 'The service 'Autofac.IStartable' is not an open generic type definition.'

Which is correct since it's not an open generic. So how do I register all variations of `OpenWindowHandler` so that I can invoke `IStartable` for all of them?

The IStartable interface is required so that they can register themselves to receive messages.

Comment: Think about it this way: if someone requests an `IStartable` instance, what concrete type should they get? Which of the infinitely many possible `OpenWindowHandler<T>` singletons should Autofac return?

Comment: That's true, as it's an open generic, the real types are not known. hmm. I guess I have to solve it in another way. thanks.

Comment: I don't know Autofac well, but naively something like `builder.Register(c => c.Resolve<OpenWindow<Whatever>>()).As<IStartable>()`?